# Where does go the mapping configuration for elastisearch-transport-wares

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use elasticsearch using the transport-wares plugin. 
It boots up, and follows the following config:

```
cluster.name : myspecialcluster

node.name : node1
index.mapper.dynamic : false
index.mapper.dynamic.strict : true
path.conf : config/
path.data : /opt/es/data
```

the problem is that it doesn't pick up the mapping files that are located in config templates. My directory structure is as follows:

```
src
    └── main
        ├── resources
        │   └── log4j.properties
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── config
                │   └── templates
                │       └── mydullindex_mapping.json
                ├── elasticsearch.yml
                └── web.xml
```

according to the docs, elasticsearch should pick up the mappings that are in config/templates

Any idea?

Comment: Did you set the `path.conf` to config or is that the default value?

Comment: I did, it points to the config dir in WEB-INF

Comment: Are you sure that setting the relative path `config` will make it point to `WEB-INF/config`? Also...sorry but why don't you take advantage of elasticsearch, its great blocking IO and REST APIs? It's just too bad to use it in a servlet container with static files...

Comment: In fact I started using the RESTapi :D

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody runs into this error this is probably caused by a mismatch between the config path.

Double check if the path is 'WEB-INF/config/elasticsearch.yml' or 'WEB-INF/elasticsearch.yml' as this differs in the examples.